# css3 transition not working in mozilla but other browsers do

Tags: jquery, css

i've been trying to run my code at mozilla im using css3 transition..

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.header').css({ 'height':'80px' });
 });
```

The problem is in mozilla there is no transition animation while in chrome there is.

Comment: What version..? Working fine for me in 33.0.1...

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5bmoxzL7/1/)

Try this:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Explanation:

```
-webkit-...  // For Webkit browser(Chrome, Safari...)
-moz-...     // For Mozilla browser
-ms-...      // For Microsoft browser
-o-...       // For Opera browser
none...      // For all browser(Newest version)
```

[**Reference**](http://css3generator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The animate option can be used which works fine in all browsers.

jquery ui is also needed along with the jquery fo the code to work.

css:

```
.header{

    height:200px;
    background:#232323;
}
```

The timing can also be specified here it s 1500ms.
The code is as follows:

```
$( ".header" ).animate({

       height: "100px",
  }, 1500 );
```